# How to alter an existing cell to a foreign key in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, relation

I have an existing database and trying to alter some of its existing cells to a foreign key. When I see the relation view, I don't see the option for establishing the relation and instead, I see "No index defined!". What would be the solution either through phpmyadmin or mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an index on the attribute that you want to make a foreign key.